# Passing ArrayList in Web Service Call in Java

Tags: java, web-services, soap, arraylist

I have an ArrayList containing 10 values.

```
ArrayList<String> a=new ArrayList<String>();
a.add("a1");
a.add("a2");
a.add("a3");
```

I am invoking WebService to pass this ArrayList as an input parameter..
However when I created a dummy client and tested for the ArrayList I am not getting the output.. I am using Apache Axis 2.
I realised that ArrayList is not synchornized and hence there may be a problem...How do I overcome this issue....
I am looking for the simplest solution...
Can anyone please guide me...

The server side code is:-

```
public class TestWebSerrviceForArrayList
{

    public String personIdentity="RandomName";
    ArrayList<String> personArray=new ArrayList<String>();

    public ArrayList<String> addValuesArrayList()
    {
        personArray.add("Name1");
        personArray.add("Name2");
        personArray.add("Name3");
        personArray.add("Name4");
        System.out.println("Added values in person Array   "   +  personArray);
        return personArray;

    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return personIdentity;
    }

}
```

The code snippet for Client Side is :-

```
TestWebSerrviceForArrayListStub testWeb=new TestWebSerrviceForArrayListStub();
AddValuesArrayListResponse r=testWeb.(I AM NOT ABLE TO FIND THE FUNCTION NAME)
```

Comment: are you passing arraylist as object/single parameter to Web service?

Comment: @ankit Can you please post your client code you are using to call the service? As The Elite Gentleman said, JAX-RS spec supports List<> and not ArrayList<>

Comment: I have a function which return ArrayList<string>..This ArrayList contains many values..At client side I will staright away create a Response and get the value..However it is not happening.

Comment: If I convert return type to Array<String> it works perfectly fine...

Answer (score 1):

`ArrayList` is not understood by the Web Service, but `List` is. It's got nothing to do with synchronization of `ArrayList` but to match the data types understood by the WSDL.

As stated earlier: I would change the return type for this method to `List<String>` as follows (and regenerate the WSDL).

```
public List<String> addValuesArrayList()
    {
        personArray.add("Name1");
        personArray.add("Name2");
        personArray.add("Name3");
        personArray.add("Name4");
        System.out.println("Added values in person Array   "   +  personArray);
        return personArray;

    }
```

Comment: Is it that ArrayList is not serialized..I stumbled across something like that however I cannot exactly recall what it is...My bad...

Comment: `ArrayList` is `Serializable` by default. I still don't understand your comment.